# What is the sample complexity of Monte Carlo Exploring Starts in RL?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, reference-request, markov-decision-process, monte-carlo-methods, sample-complexity

We can use a model-free Monte Carlo approach to solving an MDP $(S,A,R,P,\gamma)$ with transition dynamics $P$ unknown by estimating Q-values by rolling out trajectories starting from random states $s_0 \in S$ and improving the policy $\pi$ greedily. This is the Monte Carlo Exploring Starts algorithm in Sutton and Barto page 99 2nd edition.

Does anyone know if there is a sample complexity result for this algorithm?